# Get points of area border by postal code

Tags: geocoding, openstreetmap, geo, overpass-api

i would like to show area borders on google map by given postal and country code. I can draw polygon by given set of coordinates. I am trying to get needed coordinates from OSM overpass, but I have to do something wrong, because it doesnt work.

Im trying this query:

```
rel["postal_code"="11000"]["country_codes"="cz"]
```

but response is empty.

Can anyone help me how can I get areas border coordinates from OSM overpass or another way?

Comment: I dont know why, but my "hello" is disapearing from the begining of my question.. O_O

Comment: Because it adds no information to your question.

Comment: @Jolterhead Stack Overflow's guidelines suggest we make questions and answers as documentary as possible, meaning we don't start by saying "Hello" and we don't end by saying "Thank you", and things like that. Some of the website's algorithms automatically remove certain things like that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if overpass can merge results and show them as an area.

However, you using wrong tags, better to verify on OSM for correct ones. You may use `out geom` if you want just geometry data. https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/1BaV

```
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="CZ"]->.aa;

nwr(area.aa)["addr:postcode"="11000"];

out;
>;
out skel qt;
```

Zip code are not related to administrative boundaries in some countries. Best is to query for all node/way/relations with same zip code then see if there a way to get bounding area.

[image: Picture of the overpass-api Query results]